# Curio ficoides (Mount Everest)/Blue Chalksticks leaves are drying up

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, succulents

The leaves of my Curio ficoides have been drying up for more than a month now, I'm watering it about once a week, what should I do?

[image: Plant with whitened, dry leaves]

Comment: Does the pot have a drainage hole? Have you recently repotted the plant? How much water do you give it when you do water?

Comment: No it didn't but I've repotted it to a pot with holes and soil for succulents yesterday, I was watering it only once or twice a week and I was told to increase it to 3 times a week and spray it with water.